# Unable to link nasm assembly with libc function (requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc)

Tags: gcc, nasm, ld

From the nasm tutorial [here](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/) I got the following code for an assembly program:

```
    global main
    extern puts

    section .text
main:
    mov rdi, message
    call    puts
    mov rax, 0
    ret
message:
    db  "Hola, mundo", 0
```

I assemble it with `nasm -felf64 hola.asm`

However, I haven't been able to link the resulting hola.o file.

I have tried (per the tutorial) running `gcc hola.o` but that results in the following error:

> /usr/local/bin/ld: error: hola.o: requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'puts' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

passing `-fPIC` to doesn't help, and neither does `-Wl,-I/lib/ld-2.25.so`.

My attempts to link directly with ld have failed, I think because I'm missing whatever actually defines the `_start` symbol, resulting in seg fault when I urn the resulting executable.

I also tried adding a `default rel` as suggested at [nasm issue relocation R_X86_64_PC32 shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691370/nasm-issue-relocation-r-x86-64-pc32-shared-library), but that doesn't work either.

I've also tried writing the main method in C, then calling a function that calls puts in assembly. That also gives me the dynamic reloc error.

How can I link a nasm assembly file so it can call a function in libc on x86_64 linux?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by changing `call puts` to `call puts wrt ..plt`.

I figured this out after reading secion 9.2.5 of the nasm documentation: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc9.html#section-9.2.5.